# Regarding Spring integration - PublishSubscribeChannel and DirectChannel create default number of threads?

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-platform, spring-integration, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to read data from GCP pubsub using DirectChannel ([CodeReference](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-integration?hl=en#5)). When I used directchannel with maxSubscribers set to 1,2,5,10 and 40, 4 threads started processing my code for each data unit coming from pubsub, for each case.

Same was the case for PublishSubscribeChannel, default 4 threads start processing the messages parallelly.

I digged further but did not find why always 4 threads are started, which property governs this behavior and can we change it. Does somebody know why is this the case?

FYI: I did try the executorchannel by giving custom executor and the code behaves the way I expect, according to parameters I set.

Adding in system properties below if that plays any part
[System Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyuED.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is not correct. The `MessageChannel` does not do anything by itself. It doesn't not produce messages in multi-thread manner. What you see about `maxSubscribers` is really just an option to limit the number of subscribers initiated for this channel. But you do that yourself externally. The channel does not create subscribers and does not spawn threads. What you see about those 4 thread probably comes from the mentioned `PubSubInboundChannelAdapter` which is based on the `com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber` and already this one comes with a threading model to read messages from the topic:

```
private ExecutorProvider executorProvider = DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_PROVIDER;

private static final ExecutorProvider DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_PROVIDER =
    InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder()
        .setExecutorThreadCount(THREADS_PER_CHANNEL)
        .build();

private static final int THREADS_PER_CHANNEL = 5;
```

That's what I see in my `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.114.7` version. Probably in your it is still `4` threads.

You can modify that option via `ExecutorProvider` bean with a `subscriberExecutorProvider` name.

But again: the `MessageChannel` you mention in your question is passing component of your systemt and it does not consume any thread. Whatever you see is initiated from threads in the original `com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to this and just trying wrap my head around this. I just checked my Subscriber class and it does have this line:

private static final int THREADS_PER_CHANNEL = 5;

so it must be something else which controls this 4 thread part.

Comment: Well, you need to investigate what are those threads logging some info from `@ServiceActivator` and looking to manes of threads doing that for you.